# How to apply chain rule involving matrices in this situation?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

So I have a function that takes matrices as inputs and returns a scalar. So the function looks something like this:

$f(A*B)$

Where A and B are two square matrices of same shape.

Now I want to calculate

$$\nabla_A \mbox{f}(A*B)$$

And here I know the gradient when $B$ is independent of $A$ but if let's say $B$ were to depend on $A$ then what will the expression look like using the chain rule.

Let's say if $B$ is independent of $A$ then the result of the gradient is $G$ (Which is also a matrix) so will the expression look something like this, I am not quite sure if this is correct though.

$G*$$(\nabla_A \mbox{B})$

I have no idea if this is correct, or how do I proceed?

Comment: Is $A\ast B$ the product of matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @MathOverview yes

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\eqalign{
A &= X \cr
B &= I \cr
}$$
You say that you know the gradient in this case
$$\eqalign{
G &= \nabla_X f(X) \cr
}$$
Now substitute $X=AB$, and find the differential in this case.
$$\eqalign{
df &= G:dX \cr
 &= G:(A\,dB+dA\,B) \cr
 &= A^TG:dB + GB^T:dA \cr
}$$
where a colon represent the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
To proceed any further, we need to know the nature of the dependence of $B$ on $A$. Let's assume that we know the following
$$dB = {\mathcal H}:dA$$
where ${\mathcal H}$ is a 4th order tensor, whose components are 
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal H}_{ijkl} &= \frac{\partial B_{ij}}{\partial A_{kl}}
}$$
Substitute this dependence into the differential to find the gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= A^TG:{\mathcal H}:dA + GB^T:dA \cr
\nabla_A f  &= A^TG:{\mathcal H} + GB^T \cr\cr
}$$
In most cases, it's easier stick to differentials and avoid dealing with the 4th order tensor.

For example, let's assume $$B=\mu A^2$$ then $$dB=\mu\,dA\,A+\mu A\,dA$$
Substituting this into the differential expression lead to
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= A^TG:dB + GB^T:dA \cr
 &= A^TG:(\mu\,dA\,A+\mu A\,dA) + G(\mu A^2)^T:dA \cr
 &= \mu A^TGA^T:dA + \mu A^TA^TG:dA + \mu GA^TA^T:dA \cr
\nabla_A f &= \mu\,(A^TGA^T + A^TA^TG + GA^TA^T) \cr
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ the set of matrices of $n\times n$ order with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $A\cdot B$ the product of matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is derivable, *i.e.* there exists a linear transformation 
$$
\begin{array}{rrl}
D f(A):&\hspace{-4mm}\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}&\hspace{-4mm}\to \mathbb{R}\\
       &V                                  &\hspace{-4mm}\mapsto \nabla f(A)\cdot V\\
\end{array}
$$
such that 
$$
\lim_{\|V\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to 0}}
\frac{|
f(A+V)-f(A)-\nabla f(A)V
|_{\mathbb{R}}
}{\|V\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}}
=0
$$
Here the matrix norm $\|V\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}$ is equal to $\sqrt[\,2]{\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^nV_{ij}^2}$. Then the derivative of function 
$$
\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\ni A\longmapsto f(A\cdot B)\in\mathbb{R}
$$
is the linear transformation
$$
\nabla f(A\cdot B )\cdot (V\cdot B)
$$
by cause 
$$
\lim_{\|V\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to 0}}
\frac{|
f(A\cdot B+V\cdot B)-f(A\cdot B)-\nabla f(A\cdot B)\cdot (V\cdot B)
|_{\mathbb{R}}
}{\|V\cdot B\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}}
=0
$$